# Skew image using draggable handles as in photoshop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to skew image just like we do in photoshop using html5 canvas. I am able to use skew for top-right handle and the left bottom handle but unfortunately not able to apply skew on the other two handles as in code below:
The HTML:

```
<div class="scalableParent">
            <img src="img/Chrysanthemum.jpg" class="scalable"/>
        </div>
```

The Javascript (JQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var uid = 0;
            jQuery.fn.extend({
                skew: function() {
                    uid++;
                    this.attr("style","position:relative");
                    var parent = this;
                    var image = this.find("img");
                    var canvas = createCorrespondingCanvas(image);
                    var img = new Image();
                    $(img).on("load", function(){
                        canvas.width = this.width
                        canvas.height = this.height
                        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
                        ctx.clearRect(0,0,0,0)
                        ctx.drawImage(this,0,0, this.width, this.height);
                        $(this).hide();
                        //$(img).off("load");
                    });

                    img.src= image.attr("src")
                    this.find("img").attr("style", "position:absolute; z-index: -1");
                    var handles = createHandles(this, image);
                    makeHandlesDraggable(handles);
                    createOutputImage();
                    var output;
                    function createOutputImage(){
                        output = new Image();
                        output.id="outputImage";
                        $(parent).append(output);
                    }

                    function createHandles(el, image){
                        var handleLeftTop = document.createElement("div");
                        handleLeftTop.className = "handle left-top";
                        $(handleLeftTop).css({position:"absolute", width: 40, height: 40, border: "1px solid black"});
                        var handleLeftBottom = document.createElement("div");
                        handleLeftBottom.className = "handle left-bottom";
                        $(handleLeftBottom).css({position:"absolute", width: 40, height: 40, border: "1px solid black"});
                        var handleRightTop = document.createElement("div");
                        handleRightTop.className = "handle right-top";
                        $(handleRightTop).css({position:"absolute", width: 40, height: 40, border: "1px solid black"});
                        var handleRightBottom = document.createElement("div");
                        handleRightBottom.className = "handle right-bottom";
                        $(handleRightBottom).css({position:"absolute", width: 40, height: 40, border: "1px solid black"});
                        el.append(handleLeftTop,handleLeftBottom,handleRightTop,handleRightBottom);
                        $(handleLeftTop).css({
                            left: $(image).position().left,
                            top: $(image).position().top
                        });
                        $(handleLeftBottom).css({
                            left: $(image).position().left,
                            top: $(image).position().top + $(image).height() - 40
                        });
                        $(handleRightTop).css({
                            left: $(image).position().left + $(image).width() - 40,
                            top: $(image).position().top
                        });
                        $(handleRightBottom).css({
                            left: $(image).position().left + $(image).width() - 40,
                            top: $(image).position().top + $(image).height() - 40
                        });
                        return {
                            leftTop: handleLeftTop,
                            leftBottom: handleLeftBottom,
                            rightTop: handleRightTop,
                            rightBottom: handleRightBottom
                        };
                    }
                    function createCorrespondingCanvas(img){
                        var can = document.createElement("canvas");
                        can.id = "can"+uid;
                        $(can).css({zIndex: 1});
                        $(img).attr("data-canvasid", can.id)
                        parent.append(can)
                        uid++;
                        return can;
                    }
                    function makeHandlesDraggable(handles){
                        for( var handle in handles){
                            if($(handles[handle]).hasClass("right-top")){
                                $(handles[handle]).draggable({
                                    containment: parent,
                                    start: function(a,b,c){

                                    },
                                    /*axis: "x",    */
                                    drag: function(a,b,c){
                                        var cntxt  = canvas.getContext("2d");
                                        cntxt.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
                                        var dragPosition =  b.helper.position();
                                        cntxt.setTransform(1, Math.tan(dragPosition.top/dragPosition.left),  0, 1, 0, 0); // for right top
                                        cntxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

                                    },
                                    stop: function(){
                                        console.log("data")
                                        destroyAndRecreate()
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else if($(handles[handle]).hasClass("left-bottom")){
                                $(handles[handle]).draggable({
                                    containment: parent,
                                    start: function(a,b,c){

                                    },
                                    /*axis: "x",    */
                                    drag: function(a,b,c){
                                        var cntxt  = canvas.getContext("2d");
                                        cntxt.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
                                        var dragPosition =  b.helper.position();
                                        cntxt.setTransform(1, 0, Math.tan(dragPosition.left/dragPosition.top), 1, 0, 0); // for left bottom
                                        cntxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

                                    },
                                    stop: function(){
                                        console.log("data")
                                        //$(image).attr("src",canvas.toDataURL());
                                        destroyAndRecreate()
                                    }
                                });
                            }else if($(handles[handle]).hasClass("right-bottom")){
                                $(handles[handle]).draggable({
                                    containment: parent,
                                    start: function(a,b,c){

                                    },
                                    /*axis: "x",    */
                                    drag: function(a,b,c){
                                        var cntxt  = canvas.getContext("2d");
                                        cntxt.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
                                        var dragPosition =  b.helper.position();
                                        // Dont know the formula to be applied here


                                    },
                                    stop: function(){
                                        console.log("data")

                                        destroyAndRecreate()
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else if($(handles[handle]).hasClass("left-top")){
                                $(handles[handle]).draggable({
                                    containment: parent,
                                    start: function(a,b,c){

                                    },
                                    /*axis: "x",    */
                                    drag: function(a,b,c){
                                        var cntxt  = canvas.getContext("2d");
                                        cntxt.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
                                        var dragPosition =  b.helper.position();
                                        // Dont know the formula to be applied here


                                    },
                                    stop: function(){
                                        console.log("data")

                                        destroyAndRecreate()
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    function destroyAndRecreate(){
                        var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                        $(output).attr("src", data);
                        var ref = $(output).clone();
                        $parent = $(output).parent();
                        $parent.empty();
                        $parent.append(ref);
                        $(ref).on("load", function(){
                            $parent.skew();
                        });
                    }
                    $("#btnSave").on("click", function(){
                        //$(output).attr("src", $(image).attr("src")).hide();
                        window.open($(output).attr("src"))
                    });
                }
            });

            $( ".scalableParent img" ).on("load", function(){
                $( ".scalableParent" ).skew();
            });

        });
```

Any help is appreciated as long as I can understand the formula to achieve the effect required.

I've Edited the question to accomodate the conditions where I need to apply the formula for transforming the images

Comment: I think you complicated the whole thing; I just make an example, feel free to take a look at it: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/nHpXu/ (Maybe you didn't because I just skimmed through it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look WebGL library glfx.js. Filter: perspective. There will be 4 drag-able points. Doing this manually requires lots of calculations.

http://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/demo/

Answer (score 2):

You have forgot to implement cases for your "left-top" and "right-bottom" handles in your `makeHandlesDraggable()` function.  You currently only have `if` conditions for "right-top" and "left-bottom".

Comment: I know about the conditions but the problem is that I dont know the formula

Answer (score 2):

This might help you

`cntxt.setTransform(1,(dragPosition.left*10)/canvas.width ,0,1, 0, (dragPosition.top*canvas.height)/100); // for left top`

`cntxt.setTransform(1, 0, Math.tan((dragPosition.left-canvas.width)/dragPosition.top), 1, 0, 0); // for right bottom`

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palapas/UQ5S6/6/)

this link was really usefull trying to find the solution
http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/february/an-example-of-the-html5-canvas-transform-function.html